# CodeIgniter Authentication System that allows 3rd party auth?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

My question is rather simple.  Is there a system for CodeIgniter that allows both local and 3rd party login? (Such as FB/Twitter/Google etc.)

I've tried [A3M](https://github.com/pengkong/A3M-for-CodeIgniter-2.0) but it's hard to use and requires tinkering before it will even work out of the box, as is the case with outdated software.

My current solution is [flexi auth](https://github.com/haseydesign/flexi-auth), however it doesn't offer 3rd party login at all, and after an email to the developer it doesn't look like he's planning on integrating it anytime soon.

So does anyone know of a good system that is up-to-date and provides both 3rd party and local login?

If there isn't one, what other PHP framework does have such a package?

Edit for Clarity: I'm looking for a system that does both these things.  While I appreciate the answers and comments with systems that I can integrate myself, the end result of that will be shaky at best.  There's gotta be someone who's done this before, all integrated into one package so it's designed to work together.

Comment: Are you looking for an OpenID solution? Have you looked at http://thinkmoult.com/2009/02/22/use-codeigniter-openid-library-to-integrate-openid/ you can get the CI OpenID library from https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/OpenID

Comment: That would work, yes, but what I'm looking for is something more towards OAuth and OAuth2.

Comment: a3m has been forked into a cleaned up branch: https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M check it out, now includes twitter bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also looking for something like this just a month ago, but unsuccessfully. The only framework that has it all integrated in a simple way that I have seen is [meteor](http://meteor.com), but it is not a PHP framework.

I had to do it myself by wrapping different PHP libraries in CI libraries. The source code is on github: [CI Twitter](https://github.com/epoberezkin/twitter-codeigniter) and [Who You Meet](https://github.com/epoberezkin/WhoYouMeet.com-source-code) (a live web app), that has Twitter, LinkedIn and Facebook authentication and also a lot of local authentication logic with email verification and password recovery.

I know it can be considered a shameless promotion, but I hope it is useful. Although it is not exactly what you are looking for, it seems to be rather stable, so feel free to re-use it.

Maybe you will have time to extract all this logic in a standalone library (like I did for twitter) for other folks to use :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I will take a look and might use it with flexi auth to create a 3rd party login feature.

Comment: You're welcome :). Any questions like "where is this" or "why is it so" (often the reason is just the lack of experience :), feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a CI OAuth2 implementation you can use this library which is both client and server:

- https://github.com/alexbilbie/CodeIgniter-OAuth-2.0-Server

Otherwise for OpenID use this library:

- https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/OpenID

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm really looking for a complete solution, not something I can tack on to my existing auth system.

Comment: @RaptBlue What do you mean by complete solution?

Comment: Something that is integrated already.  Sure, I could add whatever I need but as I'm not the original developer I might not do the best job I could if I was the original dev.  I'm looking for something that is already integrated by the dev so that it's designed to work together properly.

Comment: There is no such integrated library such as that for CI, CI is meant to be a light framework where you add in whatever libraries you want and code them in as needed.

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up doing in the end.  Still, it would be helpful to some people to have this feature there if they need it.

Comment: I have no control over what is bundled in with CI. If you have a concern and a good reason to bundle OAuth into CI you can make your case to https://github.com/narfbg who is the lead developer for CI. However, I think the answer would be no as it would increase the footprint for the framework as not everyone would have a use for OAuth.

Comment: I don't mean bundling OAuth into CI, I mean creating a library like flexi auth or A3M that does both 3rd party and local login.

Comment: Such a system would not know how your current authentication system is setup as it would vary from application to application. So there would be no reliable way to setup local auth. What a developer does is code their system to use such code as above in the first place. There is no easy solution for something already coded.