# PHP Framework for user login

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, yii

I never used a PHP framework before and i'm searching for one right now.

The problem is i have a hard time decide wich one i should go with.

For what i saw, CodeIgniter and Yii seems to be the best ones.

I heard some things about Laravel too but i think it doesn't have a great community yet.

Some say CodeIgniter is outdated, some don't.

So yeah, everyone is saying something different.

Can someone with a great experience using some frameworks help me choosing which one is light, fast and is the best for a website with a user login system (so good with sessions, cookies...) ?

Thank you.

Comment: "For what i saw, CodeIgniter and Yii seems to be the best ones." Where did you see _this_?!? XD Regarding your question: It is possible with every framework. I prefer Symfony2, Silex, or Zend Framework 2.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/). It has inbuilt authentication that can easily be extended and I find it a lot easier to use than Codeigniter. Also has built in scaffolding generator and unit testing.

I used to use CodeIngniter but since their community went downhill a while ago and it not really taking advantage of a lot of the PHP5 features, I looked around and found Yii. The new codeigniter may be better in recent times.

You should also checkout [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). I really enjoyed coding with that and it has an amazing community and a wealth of plugins that are easy to install. Its a lot more "do it yourself" though but this gives you a lot of power.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested [PEAR_Auth](http://pear.php.net/package/Auth/) ? It is a flexible, small framework for user authentication. It supports different authentication backends as DB, Session, LDAP etc.

As it is small and specialized on authentication it integrates with existing code or other frameworks.

Like on other PEAR packages updates will be rarely on PEAR_Auth. It is also not E_STRICT compliant. But it can at least being used as a good start base for own coding our educate yourself in how such a framework can work. Like I said, it is not big and can easily being understood.

Comment: Last update 2010 and PEAR is not that known for providing upward-compatible code. Thus I guess you'll see some deprecation-errors and such and modern system, but maybe it's not the case with `PEAR_Auth`, I've never used it. Just said.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. However one can use it at least as a good base for own coding or education.

Answer (score 0):

In case framework is an option, I would recommend  [Ion_Auth](http://jondavidjohn.com/blog/2011/01/scalable-login-system-for-codeigniter-ion_auth) with [codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be faster, please try Yii with right extension. I love Symfony2 but I am waiting for next LTS release. Yii is stable and will be supported till Dec 31, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I think all frameworks are good with cookies and sessions. But when I was in exactly the same position less than two months ago (I didn't create websites since 1996 :) I decided on CodeIgniter and it worked for me because not only it has very good docs, there are fantastic video tutorials by [phpacademy](http://www.youtube.com/phpacademy) (I am in no way associated, but I would be nowhere without them).

If you've never used PHP framework before (like myself 2 months ago) you may have some hard time digesting not a specific framework logic but what they all share between them (MVC pattern), so the better the documentation the easier it will be for you. I looked at Yii too, but its docs seem to be a bit sparse.

Regarding authentication you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999441/codeigniter-authentication-system-that-allows-3rd-party-auth/14003119#14003119) of mine helpful (which is a bit of a shameless self-promotion :).

I think most people would agree that "which framework" is a very subjective question and you should be comfortable with your choice in the first place. You can also try checking and comparing the interest towards the different frameworks in [google trends](http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=codeigniter%2C%20yii%2C%20cakephp%2C%20pear%20php&cmpt=q) (CI is growing) and when you read any opinion make sure you look at the date - both CI and Yii, e.g., keep evolving.

Good luck with it, whatever you choose!